# A .txt browser/editor that has a pane on the right

Tags: windows, gratis, text-editor

Is there a .txt browser that supports a pane on the right, with the file list on the left?

I've got 600+ txt files, with different records. Sometimes I need to quickly 'surf' through different files.

I know I can make the default Explorer do this, but there is a 1 second lag when I switch to a new txt file.

I want it to be...

- Free
- Running on Win 10
- Preferably portable (small leftovers in registry/temp folder is fine for me)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

[image]

Features:

- Free (And Open Source)
- Runs on Win 10
- Portable

To open the file pane go to View -> Folder As Workspace

Downloads:
[32 bit Portable](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.5.7/npp.7.5.7.bin.minimalist.7z) || 
[64 bit Portable](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.5.7/npp.7.5.7.bin.minimalist.x64.7z)

Answer (score 0):

### [NoteTab](https://www.notetab.com/)

[image]

Features

- Create and reuse text snippets (like favorites)
- Free version (NoteTab Light)
- HTML & CSS code libraries
- Autocomplete HTML code
- Portable (runs from USB thumb drives)

[Download page](https://www.notetab.com/get.php?ntl-zip)

Comment: This *might* be a good choice, but the screenshot provided doesn't show a list of files on the left like OP is asking.

Comment: Pressing F6 appear the Quicklist whith the path and pattern that you preffer just in the left panel